# How to sort my bar values in a specific order?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-science

```
sns.catplot(x='Injury Severity', kind = 'count', data=df)
plt.title('Number of incidents by Injury Severity', size=20)
plt.ylabel('Total incidents in Montgomery County, Maryland', size = 14)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[this I want to use fancy indexing to reorder my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bRp5.png)

Comment: Then you simply present them to `plt` in that order.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: I am stuck at attempting to reorder the bars in the plot. What do you mean to present them to plt in that order?

Comment: Do they not plot in the order you gave them in the argument list?  I can't make any specific references to your code, since you haven't finished your [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My plot is perfect on my spyder IDE, however, on google colab, the plot has a different order.

Comment: You might want to use `order=[...]` to set the order for the x in seaborn's `barplot`. Note that different versions of seaborn can have slightly different behavior.

Comment: Thank you, the order parameter with the categorical values did the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to simply use the `order` argument of `sns.catplot`

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

order = ['Sun', 'Fri', 'Thur', 'Sat']
ax = sns.catplot(x="day", data=tips, order=order, kind='count')
```